# gridview with expandable collapsible rows html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I need gridview which will have with 'n' rows and each row will have 4 columns/items to be displayed. I want to achieve using Html/Javascript/Vuejs template only.

I want to achieve the following view as follows:[image]
In above picture, We have 'View All' button, Lets say we have 32 dataset, grid should have 8 rows and each row will have 4 item/column. Initially I need to should only two rows (8 item to be displayed) with 'View All' and when I click on button, it should expand and show all rows and items. with 'view less' text. when I click again, it should collapse and should show only 2 rows and 8 items.

```
<template>
  <div>
<list>
  <cell style="flex-direction:row; align-items:center ;" v-for="(rowdata,index) in griddata" :key="index" >
    <div v-for="(rowitem, i) in rowdata" style="flex:1;flex-direction:column; backgroundColor:blue;margin:10px;height:100px; align-items:center;" :key="i">
        <image class="item-icon" src="https://gw.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1788ygMMPMeJjy1XdXXasrXXa-1919-1520.jpg"></image>
        <text style="color:white;justify-content:center;align-items:center;backgroundColor:red;flex:1; text-align:center;">{{rowitem}}</text>
    </div>
  </cell>
</list>
<text class="view-all-container" v-if="viewText" >{{viewText}}</text>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      data: Object,
    },
  data() {
    return {
         isOpen: false,
         viewText: 'View All',
         borderRight: 'item-border-right',
         appearFlag: [],
         griddata:[]
    };
   },

   created() {
      for(var i =0;i<5;i++){
            var rowdata = []
            rowdata.push("1")
            rowdata.push("2")
            rowdata.push("3")
            this.griddata.push(rowdata)
         }
    },
    }
  </script>

   <style scoped lang="sass?outputStyle=expanded">

    .container {
        background-color: #fff;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
     }
    .icon-row {
        width: 750px;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
     }
    .icon {
         width: 188px;
         height: 168px;
         padding-top: 30px;
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         border-bottom-style: solid;
         border-bottom-color: #ebebeb;
         border-bottom-width: 1px;
       }
      .item-border-right {
            border-right-style: solid;
            border-right-color: #ebebeb;
            border-right-width: 1px;
       }
       .item-icon {
            width: 54px;
            height: 54px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        .item-text {
            padding-left: 14px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #666;
            text-align: center;
            lines: 2;
            height: 64px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
          }
         .view-all-container {
              width: 750px;
               margin-top: 30px;
               margin-bottom: 30px;
                text-align: center;
              font-size: 26px;
                font-weight: 500;
             color: #ef4e28;
   }
   </style>
```

Note : I had googled and verified in stack, not able to get any solution. Plz help me out of this..

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) of this? It will much easier for us to understand what have you achieved already and debug it as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ubrqz2to/5/

Comment: It's not **working**. It's hard to debug without handle with working code..

Comment: I was able to get columns but not the order I expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this. One (easy) way is to load the initial grid in the `created` hook like so:

```
 this.initialGrid = createGrid(2, 4)
```

Where `createGrid` is defined as:

```
const createGrid = (rows, cols) => {
 const grid = []
 for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   grid[i] = []
   for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
     grid[i][j] = "some/image" // could store respective image paths in an array and push them into the grid
   }
 }
 return grid
}
```

This will give you the 2 rows with four columns, provided you initialized `createGrid` as such. Then in the `data` hook you can store the grid with desired dimensions as an "original grid." The template could be as simple as:

```
<div id="grid">
 <div class="flex-container"
      v-for="rows in showGrid">
 <!-- just a placeholder, you'd likely want an img tag, etc -->
   <div v-for="cols in rows">
      {{ cols }}
   </div>
 </div>
 <button
      v-show="!toggleLoadButton"
      @click="toggleLoadButton = true"
 >
 show more
 </button>
 <button
      v-show="toggleLoadButton"
      @click="toggleLoadButton = false"
 >
 show less
 </button>
</div>
```

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxQeRV?editors=1010
This solution is limited in that you either load the two rows or all rows.

Comment: I don't want to create grid after clicking button. I need to load at once begininning and based on the click I want to decide how many rows to show..

Comment: A grid is not created on button click. Also, in your question, you only specified loading all items or only the first two rows. What you are asking here is actually different than that.